# What is the meaning of "public sphere" and "public space"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

> Civic humanism is generally taken as an equivalent or as a particular
>   variant of republicanism, meaning a conception of politics in which
>   government is in principle the common business of the citizens. The
>   “city” provides the environment ——a public space——for human
>   fulfillment.
>   http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/humanism-civic/

Can “public space” be replaced by “public sphere” 
here? It seems to me the latter is too general here, whereas the former is more specific and concrete, therefore, here better to use “public space”. But in their essence, there is no substantial difference between them, they both mean a place in which the social members work together, discussing and solving mutual problems.

Comment: No. Try to understand the context better and a little deeper, you will see why 'public space' is appropriate. They do not mean the same.

Answer (score 1):

In short I believe the answer is no.

> The “city” provides the environment ——a public space——for human
>   fulfillment.

"City," "environment," and "public space" all refer to physical locations.  I think your intuitive desire to equate this to the "public sphere" makes perfect sense.  In the greater context of the quote you provided the "city" is essentially representative of the "public sphere" in a Republic, but with that said, the city is only *representative* of the public sphere, while objectively being a "public space."

Comment: Public sphere" just is the sum of all places in which you can discuss and argue about public problems. I am sure my understanding of "public sphere" is right, because it is based on Wiki and other sources. What I am not clear is about whether you also use "public sphere" to mean public field or only use it exclusively to mean what the wiki says about it. On the other hand, I know "public space" usually means simply a physical room sharing by the public. But I wonder whether you use it to refer to an example of or species belong to the genus of "public sphere".

Answer (score 0):

*Public space* means physical space - like streets, parks and squares - which is accessible to and usable by the public. Private land may or may not qualify, depending on the access permitted by the owner.

*Public sphere* is much more abstract, and doesn't refer to any physical location, but to public information or discussion in general. Since most news is no longer exchanged at street corners or in physical fora, this would usually refer to information shared publicly on-line, or in print and broadcast media.

Answer (score -1):

I read *public space* as more literal, an actual physical space, available to the public, and *public sphere* as a metaphorical extension of the same idea, still implying that people are coming together, but not necessarily that they are coming together physically.